# CSS3 transform for smartphone don't work

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I use the css3 method `transform: rotateY(-180deg);`for display the content when the curser is hover the block.

[image: My block]

When i click on the block with my smartphone, nothing append, how can i display the content ?

**My class :**

```
#effect-2 figure .img-hover {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 10px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e74c3c;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

**HTML block :**

```
<li>
    <figure>
        <img src="img/cocacola.png" class="front">
        <div class="img-hover">
            <h4>Cocacola</h4>
        </div>
    </figure>
</li>
```

Comment: you'd need to add a touch event via javascript. maybe add the transform in a class and add the class to the element on touch. the issue is touch devices dont have hover, so it's not being triggered

Comment: What browser do you use? (Some browser isn't support the 3D transform.)

Comment: i'm on safari (Iphone)

Comment: `I use the css3 method transform... when hover` -> `When i click on the block...` click != hover

Comment: i try the Johan method but nothing append

Comment: Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7f91mkb2/)

Comment: where is the code that is on hover? the `img-hover` is already on the element. is this done with js?

Comment: i use the following code (See on bottom of the page) http://htmlstream.com/preview/unify-v1.6-production/page_jobs.html

Comment: Above jsfiddle may not work for a mobile. For mobile we need to handle touch events. Read this [developer.mozilla.org: Touch_events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Touch_events) and [html5rocks.com: Boris Smus](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/touch/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a touch event for touch devices using javascript to add you class (and trigger the animation),  i.e:

```
var myElement = //get your element

myElement.addEventListener('touchstart', function(e){
    this.className = "hover";
    setTimeout(function(){
        myElement.className = "";
    }, [animation duration]);
});
```

You'd set the above `animation duration` to match the time of your css effects (assuming they don't loop) so that it can be reused. if it does loop then you don't need to worry about it.

If you want something to work as long as the touch is active, you can trigger the removal of the class on `touchend`

Comment: I add my class in myElement and the animation but nothing append.

Comment: There is no `$('.front')` in your posted code? also `animation duration` should be a number, not two values

Comment: No, i have add (class="front") in the img :)

Comment: Not in the question. can you update the posted code with any changes. The above code should add and remove the class, if its not, please post what you have. are you getting error in dev console and when are you adding the event listener?

Comment: When i change the 'addEventListener' by 'bind' that work but the render is not good...

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
-ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform:rotateY(-180deg);
```

Comment: I added my class on my question :)

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the click event for the given element and toggle a css-class on it. Then you can specify your transformation in that class.

An example is to write your event listener inline on the element like this:

```
<div onclick="this.classList.toggle('transform-class')"></div>
```

Then later you can if you want refactor your code and bind an event listener in a separate javascript-file.

Comment: onclick="this.classList.toggle('img-hover')" do nothing on my smartphone.

Comment: You need a touch event, not click

Comment: http://jsbin.com/xomotozeja/1/edit?html,css,output   ---> This working on phone without javascript/jQuery.

Comment: Can you write your working code (in desktop view) in jsFiddle? @Ricoxor